# Can we no longer improve suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I used to be able to **Improve** suggested edits if they were better, but I noticed some typo or somesuch. It even had a check box for "This edit was helpful" or something to that effect, thus giving credit to the original editor as a helpful edit.

However, I just noticed I can't do that anymore. All I can do is approve the edit, reject the edit, or skip it entirely.

[image]

What happened to the ability to improve suggested edits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can approve tag wiki edits at 5,000 reputation, but you can't *edit* tag wikis without oversight until 20,000.

So you won't see the "Improve" button on suggested edits to tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts for another 8k, give or take.

Comment: Oooh. I never knew there was a distinction between the two!

Comment: That is a ~lot~ of rep required.

Comment: @AliceRees You'll get there! ;)

Comment: I just realized something... I never specified I was trying to edit a tag wiki! Should I be creeped out by this?

Comment: @Fluttershy Only insofar as you find other people visiting the review queue creepy. ;)